# Loop though multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array of arrays and wish to put the data in a specific order.

Here is my html form. The user(s) can add new rows to input more data as necessary.

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Date of Transfer" name="date[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Equipment Tag" name="tag[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Equipment Model" name="model[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Current Room" name="oldRoom[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Current Owner" name="oldOwner[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Current Dept" name="oldDept[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="New Room" name="newRoom[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="New Owner" name="newOwner[]"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="New Dept" name="newDept[]"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_add'>Add Row</a></td>
        <td colspan="3"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id='anc_rem'>Remove Row</a></td>
        <td colspan="3"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Then I'm putting the $_POSTed values into the $data array variable.

```
$data = array(  tag => $_POST['tag'],
                model => $_POST['model'], 
                oldRoom => $_POST['oldRoom'],
                oldOwner => $_POST['oldOwner'],
                oldDept => $_POST['oldDept'],
                newRoom => $_POST['newRoom'],
                newOwner => $_POST['newOwner'],
                newDept => $_POST['newDept']
                );
```

I figured out how to get the result I wanted manually getting the values of the $data array, but want to loop though all the data.

```
//manual retrieval
echo "</br></br>Manually getting data from the $data array</br>";
echo $data['tag'][0] . " - " . $data['model'][0] . " - " . $data['oldRoom'][0];
```

Output:

```
tag1 - model1 - oldRoom1
```

So is there and how can I write a php script to loop though the $data array in the format as seen above?

```
tag1 - model1 - oldRoom1 - ....
tag2 - model2 - oldRoom2 - ...
```

Comment: Will each one always hold the same number of entries? Like if there are 10 tags there will be 10 models and 10 old rooms and so on?

Comment: Yes. They will be set to required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output that I was looking for I needed to create a for loop. First I needed to count how many values were stored, then loop though till $i was <= $c - 1.

```
$c = count($data['tag']);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $c -1 ; $i++) {
echo $data['tag'][$i] . " - " . 
     $data['model'][$i] . " - " . 
     $data['oldRoom'][$i] . " - " .
     $data['oldOwner'][$i] . " - " .
     $data['oldDept'][$i] . " - " .
     $data['newRoom'][$i] . " - " .
     $data['newOwner'][$i] . " - " .
     $data['newDept'][$i] . "</br>";
}
```

**Outputs**:

> tag1 - model1 - room1 - owner1 - dept1 - room1 - owner1 - dept1
>
> tag2 - model2 - room2 - owner2 - dept2 - room2 - owner2 - dept2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `foreach()` loop to go through all the values, ie for the tags:

```
foreach($data['tag'] as $tag)
{
    echo $tag;
}
```

to access the same index in a different array ie to create a "match" between old rooms and old owners, you could use:

```
foreach($data['oldRoom'] as $index => $oldRoom)
{
     if(isset($data['oldOwner'][$index]))
         echo $oldRoom . " belonged to " . $data['oldOwner'][$index];
     else
         echo $oldRoom . " didn't have an old owner! :(";
}
```

Comment: Ok I did see this searching but it was only outputting the first character. So how can I echo out the first value of each post array that was placed into the $data array? Example: tag1 - model1 - oldRoom1 - oldOwner1 - oldDept1 /newline tag2 - model2 - oldRoom2 - ... ect.

Comment: That means your `$_POST`ed values do not come through as an array but as a string. Either edit the question, including the `html` form or try a `print_r($data);` to better visualize what values the array holds.

Comment: Just noticed, you need to change in your array declaration the indexes as a string: `'tag' => $_POST['tag']` and if needed then try a `print_r($_POST);` since the values should be coming through as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach()` loop -

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo 'key: '.$key.' value: '.$value.'<br>'; 
}
```